# Unable to find sum of total quantity with first shipment date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have below table where against the quantity I have Expected date of delivery. I need to find the nearest date and sum of quantity that will be shipped in.

Shipment table:-

| Item | EDD | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15-Jul | 20 |
| A | 15-Jul | 25 |
| A | 18-Jul | 15 |
| B | 20-Jul | 10 |
| B | 20-Jul | 10 |
| C | 25-Jul | 5 |
| C | 28-Jul | 7 |

The expected out should be

| Item | date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15-Jul | 45 |
| B | 20-Jul | 20 |
| C | 25-Jul | 5 |

I have tried below query

```
SELECT
         t2.item
         t2.date,
         t1.Quantity
FROM (  SELECT
             item,
             min(EDD) as date
    FROM  table 
    GROUP BY item 
) AS  t2
LEFT JOIN(  SELECT
             item,
             min(EDD) as date,
             Quantity
    FROM  table 
    GROUP BY item,
          Quantity 
) AS  t1 ON (t2.item  = t1.item AND t2.date = t1.date)
```

the output I am getting is

```
A - 15-Jul - 20
B - 20-Jul - 10
C - 25-Jul - 5
```

If I add `sum(Quantity)` anywhere in the query the result becomes

```
A - 15-Jul - 60
B - 20-Jul - 20
C - 25-Jul - 12
```

Need help to rectify the above issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming table name is `shipment`

```
select item, edd, sum(quantity) from shipment 
where (item,edd) in (
  select item, min(edd) date from shipment group by item
)
group by item, edd
```

Second version with join (always worth to check which has better execution plan)

```
select s.item, s.edd, sum(s.quantity) from shipment s
join (
  select item, min(edd) min_date from shipment group by item
) m on m.item = s.item and m.min_date = s.edd
group by s.item, s.edd
```

Comment: Thanks this is working fine and much better code